# Concurrent modification of Linux BPF hashtab map, how to make it safe without resorting to BPF_F_NO_PREALLOC flag

Tags: concurrency, linux-kernel, locking, ebpf, bpf

A BPF map preallocates memory for items by default. `BPF_F_NO_PREALLOC` flag turns preallocation off.

A preallocated map is faster. Sleepable programs could only work with preallocated maps until recently.

When it comes to concurrency, there's a significant difference:

- When items are allocated and freed individually, RCU ensures that the memory is not reused until it is safe to do so.
- Preallocated map can reuse an item right away.

Imagine a BPF program `P` obtained a pointer to a value with `bpf_map_lookup_elem()`. Neither `P` nor userspace ever modify values. However, the value DO change when the item is killed and reused for unrelated element in a preallocated map.

It looks like there's nothing `P` could do to obtain a stable view of the value, even with explicit locking (as `bpf_map_update_elem()` doesn't lock a brand new item before copying in data, which might be the same object `P` is currently looking into).

Even worse, a lookup in a map could yield a completely bogus result if the key is modified concurrently with lookup.

Is it even possible to use preallocated maps safely?

Comment: [BPF: RCU use-after-reallocation of hash table elements?](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/CAG48ez1-WZH55+Wa2vgwZY_hpZJfnDxMzxGLtuN1hG1z6hKf5Q@mail.gmail.com/T/)

Comment: [htab_map_update_elem](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/htab_map_update_elem)